# Using resources in web service itself axis2?

Tags: java, eclipse, service, apache-axis

I have deployed a web service with axis2 via eclipse. I also have a XML file to store the data that should be used by the new web service. After creating the web service, I recognized the xml file has been put into WebContent/WEB-INF/classes folder. I failed to open it with my new web service. The fault message is: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: xmlfile.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)"
I deployed it as bottom-up and the code that used to open the xml file is:

```
File xmlDocument = new File("xmlfile.xml");
```

It works when the xml file in the same directory with java file, but in the web service, it doesn't work. 
How to use the resources in an axis2 web service?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience on JAVA WEB development, but, in your case, is the XML file located in some package that has a class? If its true, you could do something like that:

```
URL url = ClassFromSamePackageOfFile.class.getResource( "xmlfile.xml" );

File f;
try {
  f = new File(url.toURI());
} catch(URISyntaxException e) {
  f = new File(url.getPath());
}
```

Comment: Thank for help but I think you misunderstand my question. My IDE is Eclipse ganymede ver 3.4.2, host server is Tomcat 5.5, axis2 ver 1.2. After building, the whole web service including resource, class file, etc will be put into WebContent folder. Now I want open an XML file inside classes folder with the path:WebContent/WEB-INF/classes. But it's hard to find the root path of this web service.

Comment: @clonevn yeap.. now I get it... sorry. :)